# how to summarize a text file into a new one using awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file like this small example:

```
>ENST00000599533.1|ENSG00000269831.1|-|-|AL669831.1-201|AL669831.1|43
FFYFIIWSLTLLPRAGLELLTSSDPPASASQSVGITGVSHHAQ
>ENST00000594233.1|ENSG00000269308.1|-|-|AL645608.2-201|AL669831.1|18
DFMHLFFIPSSELILPYP
>ENST00000420190.1|ENSG00000187634.6|OTTHUMG00000040719.8|OTTHUMT00000316521.1|SAMD11-011|SAMD11|179
MSKGILQVHPPICDCPGCRISSPVNRGRLADKRTVALPAARNLKKERTPSFSASDGDSDGSGPTCGRRPGLKQEDGPHIRIMKRRVHTHWDVNISFREASCSQDGNLPTLISSVHRSRHLVMPEHQSR
>ENST00000437963.1|ENSG00000187634.6|OTTHUMG00000040719.8|OTTHUMT00000097862.3|SAMD11-003|SAMD11|109
MSKGILQVHPPICDCPGCRISSPVNRGRLADKRTVALPAARNLKKERTPSFSASDGDSDGSGPTCGRRPGLKQEDGPHIRIMKRRVHTHWDVNISFREASCSQDGNLPT
```

this file has many parts and each part has 2 lines. the first line is ID starting with `">"` and the 2nd line is a sequence of characters.
in the ID line, the fields are "|" separated and looking at the 6th column there are many repeats of each ID. I want to make a new file from this one in which there is only one repeat of each ID and that is the one with the biggest number in column 7. so in fact in the new file I would have only one repeat of each ID (according to the 6th column) and that is the ID with the highest number (among the IDs with similar name in column6) in column 7.
the expected output for the small example would be:

```
>ENST00000599533.1|ENSG00000269831.1|-|-|AL669831.1-201|AL669831.1|43
FFYFIIWSLTLLPRAGLELLTSSDPPASASQSVGITGVSHHAQ
>ENST00000420190.1|ENSG00000187634.6|OTTHUMG00000040719.8|OTTHUMT00000316521.1|SAMD11-011|SAMD11|179
MSKGILQVHPPICDCPGCRISSPVNRGRLADKRTVALPAARNLKKERTPSFSASDGDSDGSGPTCGRRPGLKQEDGPHIRIMKRRVHTHWDVNISFREASCSQDGNLPTLISSVHRSRHLVMPEHQSR
```

to make this file I wrote this code:

```
awk -F"|" ' /^>/{(array1[val]=array[val]>length($0)) print array1}  Input.txt > out.txt
```

but it does not return anything. do you know how to fix it to get the expected output?

Comment: why did the second record with ID AL645608.2 disappear?  Or, perhaps better question is what makes the IDs equivalent?

Comment: because in the ID line in column 7, the 2nd AL645608.2 has smaller value. in the ID line, columns are "|" separated.

Comment: in the main file because I want only one repeat of each ID and that is the one with highest value in column 7. in this example I have 2 repeat of these IDs. but foe some other IDs the number of repeats could be more

Comment: what is repeating?  We don't see your actual file but only what you post here.  Can the posted output be generated from the posted input?  What are the rules?  What is the length of the line to do with this logic?

Comment: @karakfa : as mentioned in the question, every part has 2 lines. the 1st line is ID line starting with ">". in that line the columns are "|" separated. there are many repeat of 6th column in different ID lines like the example. I want only one repeat but the one that has biggest value in 7th column

Comment: Instead of describing can you please write out what ID is repeated in the posted example.  I assume "Repeat" means the same value appears more than one time.  It might be obvious to you but not to other people.

Comment: @karakfa : you are right. I corrected the question

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Adding solution as per OP's need which will provide output in same order in which IDs are coming in Input_file itself.

```
awk -F"|" '
/^>/ && !d[$6]++{
  f[++count]=$6
}
/^>/{
  c[$6]=$0;
  a[$6]++;
  val=$6;
  getline;
  b[val]=length(b[val])>length($0)?(b[val]?b[val]:$0):$0
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    if(a[f[i]]>1){
      print c[f[i]] ORS b[f[i]]}
}}'  Input_file
```

---

If you are not worried about sequence of output(like it should be same as Input_file's sequence) then following may help you here.

```
awk -F"|" '
/^>/{
  c[$6]=$0;
  a[$6]++;
  val=$6;
  getline;
  b[val]=length(b[val])>length($0)?(b[val]?b[val]:$0):$0
}
END{
  for(i in a){
    if(a[i]>1){
     print c[i] ORS b[i]}
  }
}'  Input_file
```

Will add code with sequence in output too in sometime.

Comment: actually the following sequence of each ID is also important. because I need that one for the next step.

Comment: @user7249622, I have seen that you never select an answer as correct, so please do so once you see enough answers on posts + try to up-vote to people for their answers to encourage them too, let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @user7249622, see my EDIT solution now and let me know? I am sure it will help you.

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13: just one question: is the selection of ID  based on the length of sequences in the 2nd line or the 7th column in the ID line?

Comment: @user7249622, selection of id is 1st- they should have more than 1 occurrence, 2nd- their next line's length should be HIGHEST as per your shown output, let me know if this helps?

Comment: Ok let me check some of them randomly.

Comment: @user7249622, I checked their line length for next line of ids.

Comment: one more question. if there is any ID with one occurrence, would that be included as well? because that also should be included in the outfile. I need that as well for the next step.

Comment: : seems to be correct. but the the number in the 7th column does not fit the length of next line. also would you please put comments in front of each line in your code (showing what they do)?

Answer (score 1):

if the repeated IDs are contiguous...

```
$ awk -F'|' -v RS='>' -v ORS='' 'NR>1 && p!=$6   {max=$7; r=rt $0; p=$6; print r; r=""}
                                 p==$6 && max<$7 {max=$7; r=rt $0} 
                                                 {rt=RT}
                                 END             {if(r) print r}' file

>ENST00000599533.1|ENSG00000269831.1|-|-|AL669831.1-201|AL669831.1|43
FFYFIIWSLTLLPRAGLELLTSSDPPASASQSVGITGVSHHAQ
>ENST00000420190.1|ENSG00000187634.6|OTTHUMG00000040719.8|OTTHUMT00000316521.1|SAMD11-011|SAMD11|179
MSKGILQVHPPICDCPGCRISSPVNRGRLADKRTVALPAARNLKKERTPSFSASDGDSDGSGPTCGRRPGLKQEDGPHIRIMKRRVHTHWDVNISFREASCSQDGNLPTLISSVHRSRHLVMPEHQSR
```

Comment: thanks. just would you please put comments for each line?